# Can't get simple task to run in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am ultimately trying to set up vscode to build typescript, but I first just wanted to get a simple task to run, and I can't seem to get that to work.  I now want to just run the "Hello world" task from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks, which is to simply echo a string to the output window.

My tasks.json is in the .vscode folder, and its content is:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "echo",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["Hello World"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

When I try to run the task from the command palette and choosing "Tasks: Run Task," I see "no tasks found" when I expect to see this echo task. I don't know why I don't see this task in a task list.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: No tasks found]

FWIW, my vscode version is 1.11.1.

Comment: I downgraded to version 1.5.0 and this task list and task runner now seems to work fine.

Comment: A bit farther down in the link you posted shows an example that names each task. If you use that format instead you can reference those tasks by name when trying to run a task. Not sure why their first example doesn't work though.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer If you don't name the task, you cannot expect to go anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

This works on current vscode:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "MyHelloTask",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo",
            "args": ["Hello\ World"],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "shared"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

#### What was wrong?

```
The property showOutput is deprecated. Use the reveal
property inside the presentation property instead. 
See also the 1.14 release notes.
```

Also `isShellCommand` now became `type`, etc...

Also note the escaped space in the argument. (triggers explict complaint about it otherwise. Yes, despite the quotes around it.)